# Select rows where a value on table x is 1 greater than the same value on table y

Tags: sql, unix, sqlplus

I need to create a report of all the rows where a value in table (x) is 1 greater than another value in table (y).

For example, I want to select all rows from TABLE X where the 'Total' is 1 greater than the 'Sum' in TABLE Y. So here I want to select ONLY Dai's record:

TABLE X:

| Name | Total |
| --- | --- |
| Dai | 1001 |
| Cam | 1001 |

TABLE Y:

| Name | Sum |
| --- | --- |
| Dai | 1000 |
| Cam | 1001 |

I am running this SQL in an older version of SQL*Plus so any newer methods probably won't work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the solution could be like this:

```
select * 
from X join Y on X.Total = Y.Sum + 1 and X.Name = Y.Name;
```

Comment: Thank you pal! This has worked well here (I should've known better)